# CGRectMake start point

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

guys,
I have custom UITableViewCell and some uilabels inside it. I'm using CGRectMake to replace uilabel and it's working, but I need to use rect make with start point at highest left corner.
How can I do it?

Comment: My code: [comment setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)]; but the label position changes to the center of the cell, rather than highest left corner

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're adding your labels to the designated `contentView` property of the cell. By default the origin should be at top left.